# Regex replacing everything before a predefined range of chars - Java

Tags: java, regex, string, syntax

I have string values where I want to remove or replace everything that comes before "TV|TH". My problem is that despite using the correct syntax, the string seems to stay the same.

```
 String test = "10TH";
 String replaceBeforeSide =  test.replaceAll("^\\(TH|TV)+", "");
 System.out.println(replaceBeforeSide);
```

//Desired result = "TH";

Comment: To match only the digits `^\d+(?=T[VH])` and replace with an empty string,  or `^.+?(T[VH])` and replace with group 1

Comment: @Thefourthbird I mean to replace/remove anything and everything before and not bind the condition to only digits

Comment: Then use a non greedy match or of you don't want to match non whitespace chars `^\S+(T[VH])`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Your suggestion also removes "TH". I want to keep that :D

Comment: Look at the syntax provided by @anubhava, you have to use the first capturing group in the replacement. See https://ideone.com/Q69m3T

Comment: @anubhava Your suggestion does not replace anything. It also seems I need to fix the syntax as it errors on your syntax

Comment: Sorry my bad, it should be: `replaceBeforeSide = test.replaceAll(".+?(TH|TV)", "$1");`

Comment: @anubhava, Would be awesome if you could post your last little reply as a comment so I can ping it as the solution. Hence you get good credit and other people can easily find the solution in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You could use a simple regex with a capture group:

```
replaceBeforeSide = test.replaceAll(".+?(TH|TV)", "$1");
```

or even shorter:

```
replaceBeforeSide = test.replaceAll(".+?(T[HV])", "$1");
```

Using `.+?`, we are matching 1+ of any character (non-greedy) before matching `(TH|TV)` that we capture in group #1.

In replacement we just put `$1` back so that only string before `(TH|TV)` is removed.

We could also use a lookahead and avoid capture group:

```
replaceBeforeSide = test.replaceAll(".+?(?=T[HV])", "");
```

If you want to match ignore case then use inline modifier `(?i)`:

```
replaceBeforeSide = test.replaceAll("(?i).+?(?=T[HV])", "");
```